# How to initialize/enable Bean after another process finishes?

Tags: spring, initialization, conditional-statements, scheduled-tasks

The idea is that I would like to first let a `@Scheduled` method retrieve some data and only when that process has finished enable/initialize my `@KafkaListener`. Currently the Kafka listener starts up immediately without waiting for the scheduler to be done.

I've tried to use `@Conditional` with a custom Condition, but this only is executed on context creation (aka startup). Also `@ConditionalOnBean` didn't work because actually my Scheduler bean is already created before it finishes the process.

This is how my setup looks like.
Kafka Listener:

```
@Service
class KafkaMessageHandler(private val someRepository) {

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["myTopic"])
    fun listen(messages: List<ConsumerRecord<*, *>>) {
         // filter messages based on data in someRepository
         // Do fancy stuff
    }
}
```

Scheduler:

```
@Component
class Scheduler(private val someRepository) {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "\${schedule.delay}")
    fun updateData() {
         // Fetch data from API
         // update someRepository with this data
    }
}
```

Is there any nice Spring way of waiting for the scheduler to finish before initializing the `KafkaMessageHandler`?

Comment: By default beans are created eagerly at startup, what about using `@Lazy` to have your bean created lazily (when it's required)

Comment: @akuma8 sounds like a good idea, however how do I let spring know when I need it? Currently it starts the Kafka listener whenever spring starts

Comment: Spring will create the bean when it is needed, for your listener  when a message will arrive in your topic.

Comment: @akuma8 if the application starts when there are already messages waiting on the topic, it might still be created before the scheduled tasks has finished, so in that sense `@Lazy` approach is not waterproof.